# Export TFS items with attachments and history and send them to some one who doesn't have access to local TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, workitem

We are working with an offshore development team, I need to send them on a daily basis the list of available bugs and work items from local TFS. I could not find any ready component that would help with exporting the bugs details along with history comments, and attachments.

The excel sheet thing, helps if you want to send it to some one who also has access to the TFS server.

Any clue?

Comment: Why don't you just give them access to your server via a VPN tunnel or some other solution (internet-facing TFS app tier with SSL cert, etc)?

Comment: I wanted to avoid that, as we need IT help and administration approval!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the @Daniel and @Cece for your help guys.

I created a solution using .NET TFS assemblies, to help me with this task. The tool connects to TFS and allows you to choose one of your saved queries. It will then export all the bugs / work items information into a folder as HTML, and it will include the attachments and comments on bug if any. It also creates a nice index page.

In case this helps any one, here is the link to download release one excutables from codeplex
https://tfsworkitemsexporter.codeplex.com/

please also feel free to copy the code and edit as you like

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use TFS API to get the attachments and history. Check the [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items):

```
https://XXX.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems?ids=xx&$expand=all&api-version=1.0
```

Comment: Thanks. Am going for a similar idea, which is writing an application and using the .NET TFS assemblies to help with that. Will share the code and hopefully it helps someone else :)